# How should fix emoji in wpf

Tags: wpf, emoji

i use this library https://www.nuget.org/packages/Emoji.Wpf for use emoji in my app.
but i have some problem.

```
<emoji:Picker x:Name="mypicker" FontSize="40" Cursor="None"  SelectionChanged="mypicker_SelectionChanged" Loaded="mypicker_Loaded"   /> 
<TextBox  x:Name="mytxt"  />
```

in SelectionChanged :

```
var emoji = mypicker.Selection;
mytxt.Text = mytxt.Text + emoji ;
```

if i click on one emoji its work but if i click on that again its not working . how should i fix that?

Comment: When you have a problem, you must _describe_ what you have, what you expect and what results you actually got. _"if i click on one emoji its work but if i click on that again its not working"_ - how does this help anybody?

Comment: @BionicCode  if i click on emoji twice its not working !

Comment: @Ashkan This is expected behavior, as the `SelectionChanged` event is only fired, if the selected item changed. If you select the same emoji twice, the selection stays the same.

Comment: @thatguy what should i do for fix this?

Comment: _"It is not working"_  does not help to understand a problem. It only raises another question (and maybe even annoyance) _"What exactly is not working and what does "not working" mean?"_. Let me ask you for help: I have this application. When I click the button it's not working. Can you tell me why, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to undo Selection after using it:

```
var emoji = mypicker.Selection;
mytxt.Text = mytxt.Text + emoji ;
mypicker.Selection = null; // Or =""
```

A variant of the solution with the processing of PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp and LostFocus

```
    <emoji:Picker x:Name="mypicker" FontSize="40"
                  SelectionChanged="mypicker_SelectionChanged"
                  Loaded="mypicker_Loaded" 
                  PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="MouseButtonHandler"
                  PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="MouseButtonHandler"
                  LostFocus="mypicker_LostFocus"/>
    <TextBox  x:Name="mytxt"  />
```

Code Behind

```
    private void mypicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddEmoji();
    }

    private void AddEmoji()
    {
        var emoji = mypicker.Selection;
        mytxt.Text = mytxt.Text + emoji;
    }
    bool isLostFocus;

    private void MouseButtonHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.RoutedEvent.Name);

        switch (e.RoutedEvent.Name)
        {
            case nameof(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown):
                isLostFocus = false;
                break;
            case nameof(PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp):
                if (isLostFocus)
                    AddEmoji();
                break;
          default:
                break;
        }

    }

    private void mypicker_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.RoutedEvent.Name);
                isLostFocus = true;

    }
```

Comment: the emoji change to ??? and i dont know how should i fix it

Comment: When there is no emoji selected (Selection = ""), then, accordingly, there is nothing to display - therefore "???" is displayed.
If you need to display the last selected emoji and at the same time be able to add it a second time, then you need to handle the PreviewMouseLeftDown or PreviewMouseLeftUp event in addition to the SelectionChanged event.
And add a highlighted emoji.

Comment: I cannot install the package you are using.
In my Studio Manage Packages doesn't see it.
Not on neget.org and not locally, after downloading.

Comment: @Ashkan! Somehow, I installed the package with problems - I extracted the dlls and connected them.
The package is made with many violations.
The answer was supplemented with a solution code.
The solution I propose is Voodoo magic.
It's almost a hack.
But I don’t know how to do it differently in this package.

Comment: @Ashkan , The most obvious mistake is the class Picker that derives from StackPanel.
But it had to be made derived from one of ToggleButton, Expander, ComboBox.
The last option is the best.
It was necessary to set a separate default template.
Then working with Picker would be much easier and more familiar to WPF.

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behavior, as the `SelectionChanged` event is only fired, if the selection **changed**. If you select the same emoji twice, the selected item has not changed.

The `Picker` control that you use has an internal `Popup`, but it does not expose an event for `PopupClosed` or something like `ItemSelected`. Since all the fields and methods are either `private` or `internal`, deriving a custom type does not work except for using reflection, which I do  not recommend.

Setting the `Selected` property to `null` in the `SelectionChanged` event handler is not advisable either, because the `Picker` button will just display question marks instead of an emoji (`???`), but if that works for you, you can do it.

An alternative is to create a separate button to insert an emoji in your text and leaving the `Picker` for selection of the emoji only.

Comment: that is my problem, the emoji change to ??? and i dont know how should i fix it

Comment: When there is no emoji selected (Selection = ""), then, accordingly, there is nothing to display - therefore "???" is displayed.
If you need to display the last selected emoji and at the same time be able to add it a second time, then you need to handle the PreviewMouseLeftDown or PreviewMouseLeftUp event in addition to the SelectionChanged event.
And add a highlighted emoji.